# How to change value of child input inside a parent array.map()

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make the TaskCard input component text editable here is my code:

Parent

```
state={
    taskArray: [{index: 0, task: "You are cool! :)"}]
    }

    onChangeText=(value, index)=>{
        let taskArray = this.state.taskArray.slice()
        taskArray[index]= value
        this.setState({taskArray: taskArray})
    }

    mapTaskCards =()=> {
        return(
            this.state.taskArray.map(({task, index})=>
            <Zoom duration={300} >
                <TaskCard value={task} onChange={(value)=>this.onChangeText(value, index)}/>
            </Zoom>
        ))
    }
```

TaskCard Child:

```
<input
     type="text"
     placeholder="write something"
     value={this.props.value}
     onchange={(e)=>this.props.onchange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your **onchange** property in **TaskCard** is different than yours in the "parent" component

Comment: oh wow now it works hahah thanks. solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactjs is insanely case-sensitive. Change the two `onchange` in `<input />` to `onChange`.